# Why WPBakery cause wordpress website to stop?

Tags: php, wordpress, performance

I'm having this really weird issue in my wordpress website which is hosted on GoDaddy server.
The issue is, when I try to edit any page using WPBakery, the server resources gets full immediately (Please refer to the screenshot). However on another host(bluehost) I didn't face such issue. I've tried to contact the support but it didn't help. Also I tried to optimize the website using JetPack plugin but I still get the same issue. The website will keep a good performance as long as I don't edit any page. Any thoughts what's going on?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, take a few minute of your time to take the tour https://stackoverflow.com/tour and read "How do I ask a good question?" https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You will have much better chances of getting the answer you're looking for if you. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63982842/why-wpbakery-cause-wordpress-website-to-stop#) your question with more details, informations, code, ...etc. Remember we're not next to you. For none-related code questions visit Wordpress Stackexchange @ https://wordpress.stackexchange.com.

Comment: "... Off-topic questions include those about theme development, WordPress administration, management best practices, server configuration, etc. These are best asked on the dedicated WordPress Development Stack Exchange site (https://wordpress.stackexchange.com) ..."

Answer (score 0):

Try wordpress debug and see if there are any errors when you try to update a page using wpbackery